# How to use security contraint to protect part of url?

Tags: java, security, google-app-engine

In my AppEngine Java application I have 2 rest endpoints like:

1. `/rest/rankings/current`
2. `/rest/rankings/{year}/{month}/{day}` (e.g. `/rest/rankings/2015/06/30`)

The first url should be accessable by anyone (public endpont).
The second url should only be accessable by *admin* users.

In my app.yaml I can specify security contraints like:

```
- url: /rest/rankings/*
  name: rankings
  login: admin
```

But it that case also the `/rest/rankings/current` endpoint is protected.
Is there a way - e.g. using wildcards - to only protect `/rest/rankings/{year}/{month}/{day}`?

Comment: Are you exposing your api through google cloud endpoints or any other framework?

Comment: No not GC endpoints, standaard spring mvc setup.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your methods with [@RolesAllowed](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) annotation if google engine supports this annotation or if you are using spring.

For details you can google about *Securing Methods Using JSR-250*